# Variable will not increment and register its new value

Tags: javascript, html

*What I am trying to do:* I have a button in html with the id "c1si" and onclick I have it linked to a function in my javascript that is supposed to increment by a factor of 1 a variable called "car1". Then I have an IF statement linked to onclick wired to my submit button that is suposed link to another page, if car1 is equal to 1.

MY CODE:

```
var car1
car1=0

document.getElementById("c1si").onclick = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "Green"
  this.disabled = true;
  car1++
  return car1;
}

if ( car1==1) {
  function changehref() {
    var link = document.getElementById("link");
    link.setAttribute('href', "page1.html");
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link" onclick="changehref()" ><button type="button" id="resultados"   >submit</button></a>
<button type="submit" class="stylebutton" id="c1si" style="background-color:white" > SI </button>
```

*What is the problem:* Once I click on "c1si"  I can see in the console log that car1 goes from 0 to 1, but my if statement still takes car1 as 0 and not as 1, so the if statement is false and does not redirect me to page1.html. I am really at a loss here. All I want is for my variable to increase each time I click on it so it can redirect me. Please help, Iam new to coding.

Comment: Please format your code as noted in this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your question, you're seeing the car1 variable increment to 1.  But the IF statement isn't resulting in a redirect.  In your IF statement, you are defining a function called *changehref()*.  First off, that's poorly formatted code, and I'd encourage you to define that function elsewhere.  But more importantly here, that IF statement has no reason to ever be executed aside from when the script is first loaded.

You'll want to pull that IF statement into your onclick function.

```
var car1 = 0;

document.getElementById("c1si").onclick = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  this.disabled = true;;
  car1++;

  if (car1 == 1) {
    changehref();
  }
}

function changehref() {
  var link = document.getElementById("link");
  link.setAttribute('href', "page1.html");
}
```

Realistically, since the increment is guaranteed, you could remove the car1 variable and IF statement entirely, and just call the changehref() function in the onclick.

Comment: thanks for the input this helped me, but i want to have other variables like car2,car3,car4,car5 and witch ever is the largest variable  the if statements redirects you to that variable's page on click of my submit button. so car1=page1.html car2=page2.html etc.. how would i go about doing that